# How to padding bottom of the customize EditText character?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a customize EditText character with some simple character and image.

Look like this image : [image]

But i want the image padding the bottom like this image :

[image]

This is my pwd_bullet.png : [image]

This is my code :

1. custom_edittext.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#5b5555"
   tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.Custom_Edittext">
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#fff">
           <EditText
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="60dp"
               android:id="@+id/editText"
               android:inputType="text"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:background="@null"/>
       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Custom_Edittext.java

   ```
   public class Custom_Edittext extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
        EditText editText;
        Spannable.Factory spannableFactory;
        int lastIndex = -1;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        enter code here`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_edittext);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory
           .getInstance();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
   }
   public Spannable getIconText(Context context, CharSequence text, int index) {
       Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
       if (index>lastIndex) {
           spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.pwd_bullet),
               index, index + 1,
               Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       }
       lastIndex=index;
       return spannable;
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       if (start>4) {
           editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
           editText.setText(getIconText(getApplicationContext(), s, start));
           editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
           editText.setSelection(s.length());
       }
   }

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml to custom pwd_bullet in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/layer_list"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pwd_bullet"
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:left="3dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use padding in this case, Just use a Linear layout since your items are in a straight line, and make sure you set the Linear layout to an orientation and the gravity as below. This worked for me. Good luck

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Simple Text" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pwd_bullet.png"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is an EditText not EditText and ImageView